# Need to monitor an SSR with an arduino

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay, attiny85, voltage-monitor

I need to monitor the coil side of an SSR (not actually a coil I know). The problem with my circuit is it allows enough current through the resistor divider to 0V to actually turn on the SSR. Just wondering if anyone has a better way. I initially designed it thinking the SSR circuit would have been PNP.
[image: Circuit]

[image]

Comment: What SSR are you using?  Please add a part number and a link to a datasheet in the question.

Comment: the explanation on what you are doing is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Wire the LED of a [6N137](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/6N137%20Series.pdf) in series with the SSR input (most SSRs draw no more than 10mA for 3-32V in, which you should verify).

Add a pullup resistor on the 6N137 output, plus power and ground.

Done.

[image]

You could also do this slightly cheaper by wiring a PNP transistor base in series with the high side (with a parallel resistor of perhaps 1K) and keep your divider. The optocoupler gives more isolation from EMI coupled back through the SSR.

Edit:

If you can't open the circuit, you can just increase the resistors by 100:1 (say 2M and 500K), add a 10nF cap to ground and use a 2N7000 transistor to buffer the voltage. Input to the ATTiny85 alone would actually work too (typical <50nA leakage), typically, but 1uA max leakage is too much to absolutely guarantee it. 2N7000 is 100nA max.

If you have access to both sides of the SSR you could just parallel the SSR input with a resistor but it sounds like that's another unstated limitation.

Comment: Those are all great ideas thanks. Unfortunately I cant open the loop on the SSR to put an opto in series with it. One thing I could squeeze into my very limited space would be a diode biased toward the SSR. I'll have to test it but as long as the Vf of the transistor and diode is less than the minimum threshold voltage of the digital input I think it will work. I added the picture to my first post

Comment: I increased the resistors to 2.2M and 560k, works great! Thanks for your suggestions and for understanding a clearly laid out problem and not getting hung up on insignificant details.